# Converting csv with Powershell

Tags: powershell

i have a csv that is encoded in DOS Latin 1 (Codepage 850). It must be converted to do later some replacements with powershell in the file. I have several lines in a bat file. Here the one to convert the csv and export it with a new name. If i convert it manually (Libre Office) the processing later works fine with the scripts.

```
powershell -Executionpolicy Bypass -Command "import-csv -encoding oem .\import.csv -delimiter ';' | export-csv '.\export-temp.csv'"
```

The exported file is empty. I have tried it too with adding -encoding in the output. It doesnt work. Does anyone have a idea what the problem might be? I have done several hours of researches but couldnt find any solutions.

This is the content of the csv file:

```
MsgType; Date; Time; SenderEAN; Sender; SenderCVR 
ItemInventory; 300622; 161457; 5790001405397; See; 15049847; 
Art_No; Mod_No; Description; Var1Name; Var2Name; Brand; Inv; Expe; N_No 
1001005; 1001005; Exp; green; 46; Här; 5;  ; 57073 
1001055; 1001055; Vis; green; 48; Här; 15;  ; 57073
```

Update: Here is the Error from Powershell. It says, that the Element "Här" already exists. Does anyone have an idea what it means?

import-csv  .\import.csv -encoding oem -Delimiter ';' | export-csv '.\export-temp.csv'
import-csv : Das Element " Här" ist bereits vorhanden.
In Zeile:4 Zeichen:1

- import-csv  .\import.csv -encoding oem -Delimiter ';' | export-csv '. ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Import-Csv], ExtendedTypeSystemException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AlreadyPresentPSMemberInfoInternalCollectionAdd,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportCsvCommand
  ```

Sorry when my english is not the best, hello from Germany :)

Regards, Hubertus

Update: to clarify what i want to do. In a following step i remove the 2 lines on the top, and select the columns "Inv" and "N_No" and export them to a modified .csv file. This file is always empty. When i change the encoding manually before to utf8 it works fine. For testing reason i have splitted it in smaller pieces.  Here the full code. 3 lines in a .bat file:

```
powershell -Executionpolicy Bypass -Command "gci '.\import.csv' -recurse | %%{(gc $_.Fullname) | select -skip 2 | set-content $_.Fullname}"

powershell -Executionpolicy Bypass -Command "import-csv -encoding oem .\import.csv -delimiter ';' | export-csv -encoding utf8 '.\export-temp.csv' -delimiter ';' "

powershell -EP Bypass -C "import-csv -encoding utf8 '.\export-temp' -delimiter ';' | select N_No, Inv | export-csv '.\export.csv' -delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation"
```

The output file has only the name of the columns but no values.

Comment: If you open Powershell and run the import / export csv commands do they work? You mention you are running Powershell from a batch file, my guess is you're failing to capture the Powershell error message that would tell you what the problem is.

Comment: The actual delimiter must correspond with the `-Delimiter` parameter, in other words: `-Delimiter ';'`.

Comment: @Tom thanks for your quick reply. Have added the error above.

Comment: @iRon have tried it before with the delimiter. Have tried so many thinks, that it got lost. Thanks for your advice, have edited it.

Comment: `Import-CSV` works fine with well formed data - but your data does not look well formed. The data looks like 2 CSV files concatenated together? (im looking at line 1-2 which has 6 columns, and lines 3-5 have 9 columns). You might find a dotnet CSV library that loads it but you will have problems due to the structure of your file. If you just need to change the encoding you dont need to use import-csv at all - its just a text file - `get-content` and `put-content` should do it (and you could replace `;` for `,` at the same time if thats your goal).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @MisterSmith have also tried with get-content and then with set-content. Same result.

Comment: @Community have made an update with more code in my question. Thanks for your hint/advice. Regards, Hubertus

Comment: The first command has a syntax error. If your not seeing that error i would suggest you use VSCode or Powershell ISE editors to write and debug your code before you run it via `powershell -C ...`. OR temporarily add `Read-Host` so your first command would end `$_.Fullname}; Read-Host"` to prevent the powershell window closing before you read the error, OR use `Start-Transcript c:\output.txt;` before your `GCI` to send the output and errors to a text file.

Comment: Thanks for your help MisterSmith. I have tried it too before in ISE. I have now found a solution. Its really strange and i cant tell why this happen. It has something to do with the value Här in the column brand. This column has always the same value. When i change manually this column to the far right edge, it works without any problems.